# How to switch between applications interop

Tags: c#, interop

I've made a number of unit tests and I'm using Appium to run them. In my `TestInitialize` I create an instance of word. I then open another Word doc that I need to run this certain test. I then open an excel doc as I need data from it.

I'm using interop to open my Word doc and my Excel Workbook. I'm using      `extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);` to set the foreground window. This currently works to bring the word doc to the front however I try then to bring my Workbook to the front however this doesn't happen.

My code is as follows

```
 static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
      [TestMethod]
        public void wordFormatChart()
        {




            var wordApplication = new word.Application();
            var myDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(wordColumnChartTemp);
            wordApplication.Visible = true;
            Debug.WriteLine(wordSession.Title.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(wordApplication.ActiveWindow);
            Debug.WriteLine(wordSession.CurrentWindowHandle);
            word.Window wordWindow = myDocument.ActiveWindow;

            wordWindow.SetFocus();
            wordWindow.Activate();
            SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)wordWindow.Hwnd);
            wordSession.FindElementByName("Rectangle").Click();
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

            wordApplication.WindowState= word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            xl.Application excel = new xl.Application();
            var myWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(columnChartTemp);
            excel.Visible = true;
            Debug.WriteLine(excel.ActiveWindow);

            xl.Window window = excel.ActiveWindow;

            wordWindow.SetFocus();
            wordWindow.Activate();
            SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)window.Hwnd);


            excel.WindowState = xl.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
}
```

Comment: You need to read the MSDN docs for SetForegroundWindow() to know the (large) number of reasons why it is not allowed to do its job.  AllowSetForegroundWindow() is unlikely to be useful in a unit test.  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate() is a sledgehammer that breaks all the rules.  This is all kinda strange in a unit test btw, always prefer System.Windows.Automation.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using Appium then to run the automated clicks but I didn't include that in my snippit as it's not really relevant to my issue. For the `SetForegroundWindow()` what should I use instead?

Comment: I explicitly mentioned AppActivate(), did you try it?  Advantage of System.Windows.Automation is that it doesn't require the app window to be in the foreground.

Comment: @HansPassant Should something like this work? Process bProcess = `Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").FirstOrDefault(); Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate((bProcess.Id));`